# How to launch Firefox browser using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using this python selenium code:
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/earth/Downloads/Python/geckodriver-v0.32.0-linux-aarch64 (1)/geckodriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

Answer (score 1):

I think your binary version is wrong. You are trying to launch `geckodriver.exe` which is probably the Windows version of the engine but it seems you are running on Linux.

Use [this link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to download the geckodriver-v0.32.0-linux64.tar.gz file

Comment: No i am using the geckodriver-v0.32.0-linux64.tar.gz file seems i getting error

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 127..............this error i am getting

Comment: geckodriver-v0.32.0-linux-aarch64 is really your arch?

Comment: yes i am using this file

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` in a terminal? I still think you are not using the right version

Comment: Linux pooja-Vostro-2520 5.15.0-58-generic #64~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 16:42:31 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
```

> try using `selenium ~=4.4.0`, to remove the executable dependency

Comment: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.